# Django framework view doesn't show my many to one types using nested serializers

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

Hi I'm trying to make an Rest API with django rest framework but following the docs to nested serializers after making a post request putting the custom classes values the get request show me that it's empty when I did the post correctly.

There is my models class:

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class Pista(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    km_pista = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.color)


class Forfait(models.Model):
    precio = models.FloatField(default=0)
    edad = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format("Precio " + str(self.precio) + ' edad ' + str(self.edad))


class Estacion(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ciudad = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    pais = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    pistas = models.ForeignKey(Pista, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    forfaits = models.ForeignKey(Forfait, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    km_esquiables = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.nombre)
```

My serializers:

```
class PistaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pista
        fields = ('color', 'km_pista')


class ForfaitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Forfait
        fields = ('precio', 'edad')


class EstacionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pistas = PistaSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    forfaits = ForfaitSerializer

    class Meta:
        model = Estacion
        fields = ('nombre', 'ciudad', 'pais', 'descripcion',
                  'pistas', 'forfaits', 'km_esquiables')
        depth = 1
```

My Views:

```
class EstacionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Estacion.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EstacionSerializer
```

and urls:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'estaciones', views.EstacionViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),

]
```

I think many to many is the best way to put it because I want in each Estacion a list of Pista but maybe I'm wrong I would appreciate if you can clarify me this point also.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the problem was that I was using () in the fields of the serializers instead of []. Using [] I could list them.